# How can I order a Rails collection by the attributes of associated records?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, active-record-query

I have three models: teachers, students, and assignments

```
class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assignments
  has_many :students, through: assignments, uniq: true
end
```

For any given teacher, I would like to retrieve a list of unique students - simple enough, I just call:

```
teacher.students
```

However, I would like to order that list of students based on who has submitted assignments recently. Specifically, I would like the student with the most recently updated assignment to appear first, and so on.

I am stuck on the following code, which is not working:

```
teacher.students.group("assignments.student_id").order("MAX(assignments.updated_at) DESC")
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: what error are you getting with that query?

Comment: Not an error, but the ordering wasn't working properly. Sorry for being unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that my original query was correct:

```
teacher.students.group("assignments.student_id").order("MAX(assignments.updated_at) DESC")
```

I had thought it wasn't working because I had written a bad RSpec test that was failing because I wasn't handling the timestamps well. Once I used [Timecop](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop) to handle the timestamps properly, the test passed.

Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Not really tested, but I believe

```
teacher.students.includes(:assignments).order('assignments.updated_at')
```

should work

Comment: That looks good, but I forgot to clarify that the students should be unique. For unique students, I think the .group method is necessary.